# Factorise the expression $6x^3 -7x^2-x+2$. Hence calculate the ranges of values of $x$ for which $2-x<7x^2-6x^3$

Tags: polynomials

> Factorize the expression $6x^3 -7x^2-x+2$. Hence calculate the ranges of values of $x$ for which $2-x<7x^2-6x^3$.

I know how to factorize the polynomial:
$$(x-1)(2x+1)(3x-2)$$
but I don't know how to do the second part of the question. Could someone please explain it in detail? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the factorization to begin with

Comment: Based on the inequality, are you sure you are not supposed to be factoring $(6x^3- 7x^2-x+2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2-x<7x^2-6x^3\\
6x^3 - 7x^2 -x + 2<0$

and you are going to factor that:

$a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3) < 0$

Lets look at this polynomial a little bit more, before we talk about the roots.

$6x^3 - 7x^2 -x + 2$ is get to be very large when $x$ is large.
and it is very negative when $x$ is very negative.

How can I say that?  Because when $x$ is large the $x^3$ term is going to dominate.

$a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3) < 0$

The polynomial describes a continuous curve, and that crosses zero every time x equal $r_1,r_2,$ or $r_3$ in the factorization.

Lets suppose that $r_1<r_2<r_3$

If $x < r_1$ then: $(x-r_1)<0$ and $(x-r_2)<0$ and $(x-r_3)<0$ and the product of 3 negative numbers is negative.

If $r_1<x < r_2$ then: $(x-r_1)>0$ and $(x-r_2)<0$ and $(x-r_3)<0$ and the product of the 3 has 2 negative numbers and a positive number.  And the sign of the product?

What about the remaining intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Call $f(x)=(x-1)(2x+1)(3x-2)$. You want to know where $f(x)$ is negative.  Now $f$ can only change its sign at its zeroes, namely $x\in\{-1/2, 2/3, 1\}$ so there are four intervals on which the sign of $f$ must be constant.